# Join consecutive dates from string of dates

Tags: php, date

I have a string with dates separated by a comma, and I want to calculate if any of the single dates are connected.

So the list could be:

```
2022-07-15, 2022-07-16, 2022-07-17, 2022-07-18, 2022-07-22, 2022-07-25, 2022-07-26, 2022-07-27, 2022-07-28
```

What I would like to achieve is, that I get intervals for the dates that are "connected" and then get the "single" dates "alone" like the following:

```
0 => 2022-07-15 - 2022-07-18
1 => 2022-07-22
2 => 2022-07-25 - 2022-07-28
```

Is it possible to calculate this from string to output through some exploding and going through the dates somehow?

Comment: Why is that 2nd date singled out? Because there is no collision?

Comment: @nice_dev - Yes, 2022-07-2022 is "single" because there is no "corresponding" dates (so - 2022-07-21 and 2022-07-23 is not in the string)

Comment: So we simply have to join consecutive dates?

Comment: If the dates are sorted already, it is easier with just a for loop and simple date comparisons.

Comment: @nice_dev: Yes, exactly. But I don't know if the input is sorted though :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to calculate this from string to output through some exploding and going through the dates somehow?

Yes, you can:

- Explode the string into its date-string parts
- Sort that list. Given that the format is YYYY-MM-DD, the default, lexical sort will be fine.
- Iterate that list and group entries in subarrays when they represent consecutive dates. Use `strtotime($date . ' + 1 day')` to compute what the next date would be, and verify whether the next date in the sorted array matches it. If it matches the expected date, make it the second entry in the current subarray. If it doesn't match, start a new subarray, ...etc
- Finally turn those subarrays to the string format you need.

```
function groupDates($input) {
    $arr = explode(", ", $input);
    sort($arr);
    $expected = -1;
    foreach ($arr as $date) {
        if (strtotime($date) == $expected) {
            array_splice($range, 1, 1, $date);
        } else {
            unset($range);
            $range = [$date];
            $ranges[] = &$range;
        }
        $expected = strtotime($date . ' + 1 day');
    }
    foreach ($ranges as $entry) {
        $result[] = implode(" - ", $entry);
    }
    return $result;
}

// Demo run
$str = "2022-07-15, 2022-07-16, 2022-07-17, 2022-07-18, 2022-07-22, 2022-07-25, 2022-07-26, 2022-07-27, 2022-07-28";
$result = groupDates($str);
print_r($result);
```